# How to add Purchase order info from woocommerce to the Reference section of Xero Invoice?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, xero-api

I had woocommerce linked to xero via plugin succesfully,

I had setup purchased order in payment gateway and i want the purchase order number entered by the customer at checkout to be synced with xero's refernce section of the invoice.
I tried and searched on the internet but wasn;t enough. if anyone can please help with this would be appriciated.
I had attached the screenshot of payment gateway of woocommerce for your kind reference.

[Screenshot of woocommerce payment gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5TcR.png)

Thank you

I tried going through api's and docs but couldn;t find anything related. I checked in the xero plugin settings, but there were no options to sync the refrence to woo.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to sync to the reference field but it may be that the developers of the plugin did not build the integration to include this, have you checked with the support team for the plugin?